# Spring is resetting my logging configuration - how do I work around this?

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I have a Spring Batch job that is responsible for processing incoming customer files.  One of the requirements is that logging is done to separate log files per job run (by customer).

In my application's main, I process command line arguments and then dynamically create my FileAppender from there.

My logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

My code adding the appender:

```
    private static void setupFileAppender() {
        String logDir = fetchLogDir();
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        String datePortion = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));

        FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new FileAppender<>();
        fileAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
        fileAppender.setName("File");
        fileAppender.setFile(logDir + baseFileName + "-" + datePortion + ".log");
        fileAppender.setAppend(true);

        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
        encoder.setPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n");
        encoder.start();

        fileAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
        fileAppender.start();

        Logger rootLogger = loggerContext.getLogger("root");
        rootLogger.addAppender(fileAppender);

        log.info("Logging configured.");
    }
```

Any log statements executed from my main (or calls from it) log to file as expected.  I can drill down in debug mode and see that I have two appenders on the root logger - the "Console" and "File" appenders from the two configurations.  However, once I run the `SpringApplication.run` command, the `FileAppender` disappears.

I stepped through the `SpringApplicaton.run(...)` method and what I've found is that Spring is resetting my logging configuration and reloading it from logback.xml.

From SpringApplication:

```
try {
    // Create and configure the environment
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = getOrCreateEnvironment();
    configureEnvironment(environment, args);
    for (SpringApplicationRunListener runListener : runListeners) {
        runListener.environmentPrepared(environment);
    }

    ...
```

From `EventPublishingRunListener`:

```
@Override
public void environmentPrepared(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    publishEvent(new ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(this.application, this.args,
        environment));
}

private void publishEvent(SpringApplicationEvent event) {
    this.multicaster.multicastEvent(event);
}
```

A couple of calls later, then `LoggingApplicationListener`:

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
    if (event instanceof ApplicationStartedEvent) {
        onApplicationStartedEvent((ApplicationStartedEvent) event);
    }
    else if (event instanceof ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
        onApplicationPreparedEvent((ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) event);
    }
}

private void onApplicationPreparedEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
    if (this.loggingSystem == null) {
        this.loggingSystem = LoggingSystem.get(event.getSpringApplication()
            .getClassLoader());
    }
    initialize(event.getEnvironment(), event.getSpringApplication().getClassLoader());
}

protected void initialize(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, ClassLoader classLoader) {
    if (System.getProperty(PID_KEY) == null) {
        System.setProperty(PID_KEY, new ApplicationPid().toString());
    }
    initializeEarlyLoggingLevel(environment);
    initializeSystem(environment, this.loggingSystem);
    initializeFinalLoggingLevels(environment, this.loggingSystem);
}

private void initializeSystem(ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
        LoggingSystem system) {
    LogFile logFile = LogFile.get(environment);
    String logConfig = environment.getProperty(CONFIG_PROPERTY);
    if (StringUtils.hasLength(logConfig)) {
        try {
            ResourceUtils.getURL(logConfig).openStream().close();
            system.initialize(logConfig, logFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            this.logger.warn("Logging environment value '" + logConfig
                + "' cannot be opened and will be ignored "
                + "(using default location instead)");
            system.initialize(null, logFile);
        }
    }
    else {
        system.initialize(null, logFile);
    }
}
```

In `LogbackLoggingSystem` (and `AbstractLoggingSystem`):

```
@Override
public void initialize(String configLocation, LogFile logFile) {
    getLogger(null).getLoggerContext().getTurboFilterList().remove(FILTER);
    super.initialize(configLocation, logFile);
}

@Override
public void initialize(String configLocation, LogFile logFile) {
    if (StringUtils.hasLength(configLocation)) {
        // Load a specific configuration
        configLocation = SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(configLocation);
        loadConfiguration(configLocation, logFile);
    }
    else {
        String selfInitializationConfig = getSelfInitializationConfig();
        if (selfInitializationConfig == null) {
            // No self initialization has occurred, use defaults
            loadDefaults(logFile);
        }
        else if (logFile != null) {
            // Self initialization has occurred but the file has changed, reload
            loadConfiguration(selfInitializationConfig, logFile);
        }
        else {
            reinitialize();
        }
    }
}
```

The last else is hit above, and `reinitialize()` is called:

```
@Override
protected void reinitialize() {
    getLoggerContext().reset();
    loadConfiguration(getSelfInitializationConfig(), null);
}
```

The call to reset on the context is what resets everything.  The thing is, that digging into the `loadConfiguration` method also calls the reset method the logging context.

Any ideas on how to get around Spring resetting my logging configuration?

FYI, I'm using 4.1.4.RELEASE version of Spring.

Comment: This question isn't Spring or Spring Batch related, it all has to do with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like deferring your customisation of the logging configuration until after `LoggingApplicationListener` has run should work.

`LoggingApplicationListener` performs its initialisation in response to an `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` and has an order of `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 11`. To prevent your custom configuration from being overridden, you could encapsulate your customisation logic in a `SmartApplicationListener` that responds to the same event but with a lower order so it runs after `LoggingApplicationListener`:

```
public class CustomLoggingConfigurationApplicationListener implements
    SmartApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {    
        // Customise the logging configuration
    }   

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 12;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsEventType(Class<? extends ApplicationEvent> eventType) {
        return ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent.class.isAssignableFrom(eventType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsSourceType(Class<?> sourceType) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

You can create the listener and register it in your application's main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .listeners(new CustomLoggingConfigurationApplicationListener())
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: 100% spot on answer.  Thank you Andy.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but this solution doesn't work for me. I had already got to this same "potential solution" by myself, but for some reason my listener is never has a chance to listen to the ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent, and others. For example, if I add a break point to supportsEventType all it gets called for is: ContextRefreshedEvent, EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent, ApplicationReadyEvent and ContextClosedEvent. ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent, which is supposed to be earlier than all these other events, never triggers my listener. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Just found out why in my case it didn't work. I registered my listener using @Import in the Application class, instead of directly calling listeners method in SpringApplicationBuilder. Because of that, my listener was not registered on time for many events, including ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent. I wonder if that behavior is expected (and documented) or if it is a bug.

Comment: Yes, that's expected. `@Import` isn't processed until the application context is refreshed.

Comment: True. And it is actually documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners)

Comment: In newer versions the `LoggingApplicationListener` is already having `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 20`. That being said I change it to `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 30` it still does not work