# Spring Boot and Log4j

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, java-8

Is it possible to load different **log4j** configuration based on which spring boot profile I am using.

Let's say I have in **application.properties**

```
log.level=DEBUG
log.path=/opt/tomcat/logs/blabla.log
log.appender=CONSOLE
```

and in **application-live.properties** I have different values for all 3

```
log.level=WARN
log.path=/crazy/tomcat/logs/blabla.log
log.appender=FILE
```

and in **log4j.xml** I have definition for CONSOLE appender, FILE appender, and multiple loggers

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${log.path}" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="8MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="50"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [${project.artifactId}-${project.version}] %p [SearchID - %X{searchID}] %c{1}.%M(%L) %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [${project.artifactId}-${project.version}] %p [SearchID - %X{searchID}] %c{1}.%M(%L) %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

<logger name="com.mchange" >
        <level value="${log.level}" />
        <appender-ref ref="${log.appender}" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="java.sql" >
        <level value="${log.level}" />
        <appender-ref ref="${log.appender}" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="${log.level}" />
        <appender-ref ref="${log.appender}"/>
    </logger>
<root>
        <level value="${log.level}"/>
        <appender-ref ref="${log.appender}"/>
    </root>
```

So I have to inject all 3 values in different places in **log4j.xml**
This configuration is not working right now, since when I use **-Dlog4j.debug** to check what is going on I see that all the values for the properties are missing, like they are not loaded from **application.properties** at the time when log4j configuration is being loaded. Is there a way to accomplish this. I've read all of the spring-boot documentation, as I can see there is no example where I use both application properties and explicit log config like log4j which I need. I also need to add, that I cannot use logback instead of log4j.

Comment: You should consider switching to logback or log4j2

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate folders in `src/main/environment` for different configurations according to the environment.

Then if you use `gradle` build like this,

```
./gradlew build -Penv=prod
```

Then, to catch the environment add following to your `build.gradle`,

```
 project.ext {
 environment = "dev"
 }

 loadConfiguration()

 def loadConfiguration() {
    project.environment = hasProperty('env') ? env : 'dev'
 }
```

Then copy the config using following while build. (Move this to separate file called `copy.gradle` and use `apply from: 'copy.gradle'` at the top of your build file),

```
task copyConfiguration << {
println "Target environment: $environment"
  copy {
    from "src/main/environment/$project.environment"
    into "src/main/resources"
    include "*/"
  }
}
```

---

For `maven` it seems easy than `gradle`,

```
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/dev</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/prod</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

and build like `mvn install -Pdev`, I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512516/how-to-copy-a-resource-or-another-in-maven-depending-on-the-target-environment), and read [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html) for some more info.

Comment: I should have added that I use MAVEN for build.

Comment: You can do the same with maven, but i dont have any code right now

Comment: Thanks @Maleenc I understand your answer know, we used to have these maven profiles before we switched to spring-boot. Altough I did find something similar, I deployed WAR and in command line added -Dlogging.config=classpath:log4j-local.xml , this way I choose which log4j configuration will be used at deployment time, but I need to have fixed values in it for properties like Level, Path, Appender... I guess it's something

Comment: I would appreciate, If you could rate or accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to have desired implementation with multiple log4j.xml files, one for every profile (log4j-dev.xml, log4j-loca.xml etc.)
and with custom LoggingApplicationListener that I implemented based on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28433944/1094300). 
I copied most of the code from spring's LoggingApplicationListener, I amended changes for methods like in the answer in link, and I refactored method

```
private void initializeSystem(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, LoggingSystem system) {
        LogFile logFile = LogFile.get(environment);
        String activeProfile = environment.getActiveProfiles()[0];
        String logConfig = "classpath:log4j-" + activeProfile + ".xml";
        if(StringUtils.hasLength(logConfig)) {
            try {
                ResourceUtils.getURL(logConfig).openStream().close();
                system.initialize(logConfig, logFile);
            } catch (Exception var6) {
                this.logger.warn("Logging environment value \'" + logConfig + "\' cannot be opened and will be ignored " + "(using default location instead)");
                system.initialize((String)null, logFile);
            }
        } else {
            system.initialize((String)null, logFile);
        }

    }
```

This is for example that you have only one active profile at a time. For multiple profiles I have no answer.